# Report result - Can SQL be improved?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am creating a report of Shops Order. SQL Query does work as expected.

It calulate the numbers of orders from each shop, the total cost of orders and our commission and the outstanding fields.

If the customer paid by Cash at the delivery, then it show `OutstandingComm` field
If the customer paid by Card from Online, then it show `outstanding_shop` field

```
SELECT T.ShopID, T.company, O.order_id, count(*) as NumOfOrders, 
       sum(O.shop_remaining) as ShopEarnings, 
       sum(O.comm_grandtotal) as OurComm, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_method = 'PayCash' AND status = 1 THEN O.comm_grandtotal ELSE 0 END) as OutstandingComm,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_method = 'PayCard' AND status = 1 THEN O.shop_remaining ELSE 0 END) as outstanding_shop
FROM Shops as T 
      JOIN orders O ON O.ShopID = T.ShopID 
Group by ShopID
```

Can this SQL query could be improved or is there alternative better way?

Comment: Can't see anything out of the ordinary there. What are you expecting?

Comment: Looks good to me... If I had to come up with something, it would just be style.  The first two 'sum' functions are in lowercase, next two are in caps.  Also, 'SELECT' and 'FROM' are in caps, but 'Group by' isn't.

Comment: StackOverflow is mostly for solving actual problems. For reviewing you could try posting it on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things I can think of:
Here are some things to consider, try them if you feel like it, but be sure to time the effect of each change, it might not work or it might make things slower:

1. The `case when` looks at a string *(PayCash/PayCard)*. If you make that field a number, put an index on it and check the numeric value, it might run faster.  The index might not get used though because it has a low cardinality.
2. If you use InnoDB, try and put an index on shops.company. This way MySQL can use the covering index for shops.company to retrieve the `companyname` and doesn't need to do a full table read on table shops.
3. You might consider partitioning the tables by field `status`. Status has low cardinality, so an index will probably not be used, but if you partition, MySQL will only read from the status=1 version of the table, only do this when there are a **lot** of `status=0` fields.
4. You are currently selecting **all** transactions, this is a bit unlikely. Partition the table by year or month and select only the current year or month.
5. I'm sure you already have a primary autoincrement keys on `shops.shopid`.
6. You should also have an index on `orders.shopid`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion/advice. That was helpful. I dont understand number (3), can you clarify what you mean and include example? Thanks!

Comment: Also all my tables are MyISAM. Is there advantage changing to InnoDB?

Comment: There might be, InnoDB can use covering indexes, see here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/

Comment: If you partition a table, MySQL splits it in parts, if you put all status=1 parts in one table and all status=0 parts in another it might work faster, although I doubt it, was just listing it to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL already looks good. You are already doing the best you can for your design.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a Maxwell House coffee guy...to the last drop!...looks good to me, however, consider a WHERE clause as data may grow in the future...could do the same by dropping an AND on the current JOIN.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... Do the OP's requirements call for filtering of some sort? If not, why would you consider adding a WHERE clause? What would the clause contain?

Comment: dude...I have't seen the OP's requirement doc...he/she asked if it could be improved...I was just offering my [suggestion]...I am sure the business plans on getting more stores in the future. Perhaps a date range when stores were added, maybe a transaction date, if he/she has one in the db.